# Two openvpn connections: one with redirect-gateway and a second one for private network

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn

I have a personal VPN that I use as a default gateway for all Internet traffic when I'm on the road.  This works great and I have no problem.

I also have a work VPN, which I need to connect to reach machines on their private network.

What I want to do is use these together.  Unfortunately, `redirect-gateway def1` on my personal VPN appears to redirect *everything, including traffic that should go over the work interface*.

For example:

```
utun3: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.192.6 --> 192.168.192.5 netmask 0xffffffff
utun4: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet 1.2.3.4 --> 1.2.3.4 netmask 0xfffff800
```

above `utun3` is the personal network interface that redirects everything and `utun4` is the work network interface that i need to connect to certain machines.

I have tried setting routes to no avail.  Work machines are on the `172.31.0.0/16` network and I've tried to set routes such as:

```
route 172.31.0.0 255.255.0.0 utun4 0
```

but the connection just hangs. 
How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct syntax for the `route add` command would be:

```
route add -net 172.31.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 1.2.3.1
```

I am guessing on the gateway (gw) number;
you would need to ask your office's IT support about this
if you can't figure it out by diagnostic tools. 
(Or, if I understood the first part your question correctly,
then you can use the `def1` hostname.)

The reason you can't route it to the interface name directly, is because the network you are routing is not local on that interface.